# Logging in to Laravel Nova using multiple guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm trying to setup a Laravel Nova panel where multiple models can login & have different access via policy methods etc.. 
But it seems there isn't a documented way to do so.

Appreciate any idea or solutions.